# Wordpress Redirect login

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

im in trouble with a redirect after login ..
So.. my member plugin "armember" have in general settings the "referral link" about redirection and a default link if its missing..

i'd used php snippet in function to redirect the woocommerce pages if user not logged in.

this is the snippet :

```
  'add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access');
    function wc_redirect_non_logged_to_login_access() {
      if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( is_woocommerce() || is_shop() ||is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page() ) ) {
      wp_redirect( get_option('home') . '/login?redirect_to=' . esc_url($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) );
    exit();
   }
}'
```

the main purpose is to redirect to called page after login...
for example.. /myaccount > login page > back to /myaccount
or calling /shop > login page > back to /shop...

someone can help me?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use the `$_SERVER` variable you can get that information from WP.

Here is what I use when I do login redirects.

This is the login link that I add to the header template.  The link sets the `redirect_to` parameter.

```
<div id="login">
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo sprintf( '<a href="/my-account/" class="account-btn mx-2"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i></a><a href="/wp-login.php?action=logout" class="logout-btn ml-1"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a>', esc_attr( $user->first_name ), wp_logout_url( home_url() ) );
    } else {
        global $wp;
        $redirect = urlencode( trailingslashit( site_url() ) . $wp->request );
        echo sprintf( '<a href="/my-account/?redirect_to=%s" class="login-btn"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ' . __( 'Login', 'dd_theme' ) . '</a>', $redirect );
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Then I add this filter to the `woocommerce_login_redirect`

```
// Login Redirect to Previous Page.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'dd_custom_login_redirect', 10, 2 );
function dd_custom_login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    $my_account = get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) );
    if ( isset( $_GET['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        $redirect = esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_GET['redirect_to'] ) );
    }
    return $redirect;
}
```

Comment: Nope, redirect not work, after login goes to home page..

Comment: I've updated the answer with what I currently use for login links.